# Ext 4 ComboBox custom trigger

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, combobox, triggers

I need to customize the trigger in Ext 4.2 ComboBox . I need to customize the icon to Magnifying glass and to be able to switch the icon to X icon as I start typing.
Can someone give me an example of how it's done ?

Thank you !!!

[image]

Comment: Hi did you figure it out? I need exactly that behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.form.field.ComboBox` has two methods: expand and collapse which are called when the field's picker are expanded and collapsed, respectively. Since the icon is set in a CSS class, it seems like you could pretty easily swap the CSS class based on these events.